# SQL encoding - Long dash in Visual Studio converts into � in the version management tool

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, encoding, special-characters, github-desktop

I'm trying to insert new row into a database containing text with special characters like long dash (—). When I do this manually in my SSMS - it works okay, but when I commit the script into my version management tool (Github desktop), these symbols show up as �. In Visual Studio special characters show up normally as well. What should i do so that I can add the script properly and it could be executed potentially against any SQL Server 2016 database?
[image]

How my changes appear in Github Desktop:

[image]

Comment: Is this allow Changing encoding?

Comment: First of all, if you're going to use characters outside ASCII, make your string constants Unicode by prefixing them with `N` -- even if your columns are `VARCHAR` with a collation that happens to support them. Second, check how the file is saved -- in VS, you can do File -> Save As, then click the Save button to get the "Save with Encoding" option. UTF-8 with BOM would be a good choice for files like this on Windows, but some tools might mishandle the BOM. As long as the encoding of the file and the characters in it is OK, how your diff tools handle it is a separate concern.

Comment: Jeroen Mostert - Thank you. This will help.

Comment: What does N at the beginning do?

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#unicode-strings). The `N` ensures the character string has a consistent encoding regardless of where it occurs. Without it, you can get surprises with strings that are encoded in collations other than the target collation of the column. This especially matters when you're using characters that will not actually fit in a `VARCHAR` (like a Chinese character in a database using a Latin collation). Of course, to store those correctly at all you still need an `NVARCHAR` column as well.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the behavior is caused by the encoding type for the *.sql file to where I put my script with special characters. The file uses UTF-8 encoding, while it should be saved using UTF-8-BOM encoding to be able to display those characters correctly.

[image]